# (CSS) Media query

Tags: html, css, media

11 november 2015

Hey everyone,

I am making a website, and I have a problem with css media queries.
First let me show you my code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    #services {
        width: 90%;
    }  
    
}

#services {
    text-align: center;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(197, 197, 197, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(197, 197, 197, 1);
    box-shadow:         0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(197, 197, 197, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id='services'></div>
```

So this is my code (not that hard right), but as you can see I want to change the width of de services container when the browser window in smaller than 1100. But it doesn't change the width! I had this problem before and I fixed it but now I really cant.

Can someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Beer Yolo

Answer (score 5):

Your media query needs to be defined below the standard CSS rules, so that it is able to override them.  As it is now, your standard rule for `#services` is overriding the media-query rule for the same.

Comment: ya just beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you it works now, also thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

If that's all you need the media query for, you can drop it and update your 
`#service` rule like this:

```
width: 90%;
max-width: 1100px;
```

Sample snippet

```css
#services {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(197, 197, 197, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(197, 197, 197, 1);
    box-shadow:         0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(197, 197, 197, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id='services'></div>
```